# How to get the creation date of a file that is present on HDFS?

Tags: scala, hadoop

I am working on a Scala-Spark program that needs to take latest created file(a file gets created in a dir everyday) from a directory on HDFS and read the data in it for further processing. 
From my research I've found below code to get the file that is 2 days older using Scala:

```
import java.nio.file._
import java.time._
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS
val isMoreThan2DaysOld = Files.getLastModifiedTime(path).toInstant.plus(2, DAYS) isBefore Instant.now
```

But this code doesn't work for a file that is present on HDFS. Could anyone let me know how can I implement picking latest created file from a directory that is present on HDFS using Scala.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the normal hadoop filesystem Apis in scala to get the file modified date. and pick the latest one.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

val conf = spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
val fs = FileSystem.get(conf)
val dirPath = new Path("csvdatatest")
val filestatus = fs.listStatus(dirPath )
filestatus.foreach(f => println(f.getModificationTime))
```

This will list the filemodification/creation date of all the files in descending order. You can pick the latest file as the first file.

Note: If you are using sparkcontext to get the hadoop configuration then you dont need to specify explicitly the core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml in configuration. As i have used above.

But you can create your configuration as below pseudo code:
specify your path for core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml

```
val conf = new Configuration();
conf.addResource(new Path("<core-site-path>/core-site.xml"));
conf.addResource(new Path("<hdfs-site-path>/hdfs-site.xml"));
val fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
```

Comment: The line: 
val dirPath=new Path("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/pigdata") has a problem as the path of the file on "dirPath" is wrong.

Error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/pigdata, expected: file:///

If I try it with file:///:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/pigdata does not exist

core-site.xml has the property:
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020</value>
  </property>
what is the mistake I am doing here ?

Comment: 1- Your default file system in Spark seems to be set on localfs, you need to set it to hdfs.  2- `val dirPath=new Path("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/pigdata")` uses the Path of the java.io library.
try to use the full class name like this 
`org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path` then you can try
`val dirPath=new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/pigdata")`

Comment: is there equivalent code in pyspark?